# How to show google navigator with voice directions over your App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I had tried the below code but it just open the google map:

```
NSString *latlong = @"-56.568545,1.256281";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@",
[latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

But how to set the current location and destination location by default so the user doesnot need to type the location.and the navigator automatically get start.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge i have found two options.

- skobbler or sk maps (http://developer.skobbler.com/)
- HERE Maps (https://developer.here.com/)

HERE Maps is somewhat costly and does not allow free usage (only 90 days of trial period). But it has lots of advantages like:

**Clear and perfect documentation:** The documentation they provide is clear and easily understandable, also the demo app they provide has all the required things implemented. So you can copy-and-paste many things.

**Developer friendly:** Full control of maps for developers (no restrictions, you can do anything that you can think of with maps).

**Coverage:** Navigation is not only clear and good for some specific countries, but for almost all countries. I have checked it in India for example. Apple Maps is not providing routes in India, Google Maps are providing it, but from my perspective, HERE Maps is much clearer and even better than Google.

skobbler is good and allows free usage up to a limit, but it's not good for all countries (not covering India up to level). Also it is not that much developer friendly as HERE Maps.

Comment: Actually we cannot afford this , somehow google provides it for free. Just need to open the google map app for navigation not any third party. But thanks for you response. Really appreciated.